# how to check 2 unique fields in mysql query

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables:
questions:

```
-----------------------
active | question | qid
-----------------------
   1   |   "bla"  | 5
   1   |   "bla"  | 6
   1   |   "bla"  | 7
   0   |   "bla"  | 8
```

answers:

```
-----------------------
userid | answer   | qid
-----------------------
   1   |   "bla"  | 6
   2   |   "bla"  | 5
```

userid and qid are unique
i want the questions (question, qid) that are active is 1, and that the user x is not answer on it.

i have the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT questions.qid , questions.question
FROM questions
JOIN answers on (answers.userid = 1)
where questions.active = 1 and (answers.qid != questions.qid)
```

but its good only for user 1 (give us qid: 5,7).
i want to upgrade the code that will be good also for user 3 (will give us qid: 5,6,7)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case that you can use EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.qid , q.question
FROM questions q
WHERE q.active = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM answers
  WHERE userid = 1 AND qid = q.qid
)
```

You can change `WHERE userid = 1` to `WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)` to check for multiple users as well.